# WooCommerce: How to check product quantity with custom stock in cart

Tags: woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce, I have products that have a custom field "_stock_custom" in addition to the standard "_stock". I solve this by adding the information at the filter `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'filter_add_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
function filter_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) { 
    $cart_item_data['select_stock'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['select_stock'] );
    if ($cart_item_data['select_stock'] == 'custom') {
        $cart_item_data['custom_stock'] = get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_stock_custom', true );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

I have added the stock option before the Add to cart button via `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` action:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' );
function action_woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button() {
    echo '
<select name="select_stock" id="select_stock">
  <option value="standard">Standard Stock</option>
  <option value="custom">Custom stock</option>
</select>
    ';
}
```

The problem is, if I want to check if the product (including information about the specific stock) is in the cart and what is the number of products before adding it to the cart. I use the filter `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` for this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'my_validation_handler', 10, 5 );
function my_validation_handler( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
    $stockCustom = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
        
        if ($variation_id . $cart_item['select_stock'] == $_POST["variation_id"] . $_POST["select_stock"]) {
            if ($cart_item['select_stock'] == 'custom') { $stockCustom = $stockCustom + $cart_item['quantity']; }
            $maxStockCustom = get_post_meta($variation_id, "_stock_custom", true);
            if ($_POST["select_stock"] == 'custom') {
                if ($quantity < $maxStockCustom) {
                    if (($stockCustom + $quantity) > $maxStockCustom) {
                        wc_add_notice( __('You already have the maximum quantity available in your basket from the stock listed.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    wc_add_notice( __('Such quantity is not available in the mentioned stock.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

However, it only works if the product that has custom stock is already in the cart. If I add a product from Custom Stock of 1 piece to my cart and then want to add another 5 pieces, when only 3 pieces are allowed in _stock_custom, it will not add it correctly. However, if I add a product with 5 pieces without the same product previously in the cart, it will add it to me, which is incorrect.

My intention is that before adding a new product to the cart, the filter will look up the currently added product or product variant in the currently added products in the cart (also with the stock comparison that is sent in $_POST["select_stock"]) and only allow to add as many pieces as there are in "_stock_custom", and in case the product is not in the cart, to check if the total number of pieces to be added is not more than "_stock_custom".